# Update Software via Berksfile Version Constraint

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant, berkshelf

Using vagrant + Berkshelf, I'm trying to update my already existing VM to a newer `git` version.

**Vagrantfile**

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

# Vagrantfile API/syntax version. Don't touch unless you know what you're doing!
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  # Every Vagrant virtual environment requires a box to build off of.
  config.vm.box = "centos_64" # CentOS 6.5 box

  config.vm.box_url = "https://github.com/2creatives/vagrant-centos/releases/download/v6.5.1/centos65-x86_64-20131205.box"        # URL of the `centos_64` box

  config.berkshelf.enabled = true  # use Berkshelf
  config.omnibus.chef_version = :latest     # install chef

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"] # speed up networking on guest
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]        # ditto
       vb.memory = 1024                                              # 1 GB RAM for guest VM
       vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpuexecutioncap", "75"]     # 75% of CPU goes to host VM.
  end
end
```

**Berksfile**

`cookbook 'git', '>= 1.9.0'`

Note that I added the version constraint after the VM was created.

However, when running `vagrant reload --version`, no software update was made to the `git` version.

Additionally, destroying the VM, and then running `vagrant up --provision` does not result in installing the v 1.9.0 (or better) version of git.

Why's that?

Comment: This question was asked as an issue on the project. https://github.com/berkshelf/vagrant-berkshelf/issues/154

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify that,  Seth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want version 1.9.1 of git installed, you will need to have something like this in your vagrant file:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
    chef.json = {
      "git" => {
        "version" => "1.9.1",
        "checksum" => "8e300c0b72c2738ca273c38ea9566d5326d554f8bb5f4d6aa40c87783edcd153"
      }
    }
    chef.add_recipe "git::source"
end
```

Where version is the version of git you want to download (this will become "`https://nodeload.github.com/git/git/tar.gz/v1.9.1`")

checksum is a sha256sum of the downloaded file to verify the contents

chef.add_recipe "git::source" will install git from source (the downloaded file above) as opposed to getting it from yum or apt or whatever package manager your distro is using.

Git 1.9.1 will be installed to /usr/local but if you have already got git installed in /usr/bin then you may need to uninstall that first.

Comment: Hi mwalton - got this exception when adding the above and then running `vagrant provision`: `[vagrant@vagrant-centos65 vagrant]$ sudo cat /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Generated at 2014-03-19 15:19:11 +0000
Chef::Exceptions::Package: package[kernel-devel] (build-essential::rhel line 35) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::Package: No version specified, and no candidate version available for kernel-devel`.

Comment: try putting chef.add_recipe "yum" above chef.add_recipe "git::source". The problem appears to be that the depenency packages for build essential (required to build git from source) is unavailable in the yum repo you are using. This might be because the yum cache is out of date or clear. running the yum recipe first should update the boxes yum cache.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a provisioner:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.add_recipe "git"
end
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. I added this and ran `vagrant reload --provision`, yet my `git` still shows 1.7.1 when running `git --version`.

Comment: The version of the git cookbook is not the same as the version of git.... The default recipe will install the latest git package. What RPM package repository have you configured and what is the latest version available? I suspect it's 1.7.1.... (see: https://github.com/jssjr/git/blob/master/recipes/default.rb)